# Extending columns of the admin user grid Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I use Kentico 10.
I **try to show new custom columns** in the **user grid**. (please see picture below)


What's the best way to do it, 

so that it still works after a Kentico update?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do is create your own XML file based on this file:

`/CMSModules/Membership/Pages/Users/User_List.xml`

and add your field like so:

`<column source="##ALL##" externalsourcename="#transform:cms.user:PriceListAllowed#isnullyesno" caption="Price List Allowed" allowsorting="true"/>`

Second, you'll need to create a query which gets the fields you're expecting.  Look in the current XML file and you'll see the object it's referencing is an object which is created in code and you have no control over it:

`<objecttype name="cms.userlist" />`

The `cms.userlist` is essentially calling the `View_CMS_User` view.  You have a few options:

- Modify the existing view (not recommended)
- Create your own query in the Membership module on the User class which will join the `cms_user` table to the `cms_usersettings` table and selects " * " for the list of columns and it will automatically include your new columns.

Then go back to the XML file you created and remove the objecttype node and add a `<query>` element like so:

`<query name="cms.user.yourcustomqueryname" />`

This should get you what you're looking for.  The only thing which may be overwritten in an upgrade would be the path to the Users XML file in the User module.  So that should be pretty easy to update that path if it is overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I did it, all according to the instructions.
Now I'm getting an Error.   **Message: Column 'UserHasPassword' does not belong to table Table.** .   If I comented it out `<action name="haspassword" externalsourcename="haspassword" caption="$userlist.nopassword$" fonticonclass="icon-exclamation-triangle" fonticonstyle="warning" />` and try to edit a User, I'm getting **Message: The GridView 'v' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.**

Comment: In the XML file, remove the "columns" attribute and value.  It looks like the back-end code needs more columns in order to perform the other events.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit [unigrid definition](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/references/kentico-controls/ui-controls/unigrid/reference-unigrid-definition) file located at `~/CMSModules/Membership/Pages/Users/User_List.xml`

I've tried with `<column source="##ALL##" externalsourcename="#transform:cms.user:PriceListAllowed#isnullyesno" caption="PriceListAllowed" allowsorting="true"/>` and it does not seem to work. Your probably need to add columns to the grid query, this means you have to create Unigrid Extender (here is an [example](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/extending-unigrid-and-filtering-options)). Take a look also at [creating extenders](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/creating-extenders-for-module-interface-pages).

P.S. You might as well put your column in usersettings and use it as reference tabl. here is an [example](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/edit-customer-fields-displayed-on-e-commerce-customer-module)

Comment: Updating only the XML file will not work as there is some custom object type which is created in Kentico Source Code which you cannot modify.  I've provided instructions in my answer which should get the OP the result he's expecting.